# What parameters can a fourier transformation have? / How to process the shifted result?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, fft

I have a simple Python 3 TKinter Image Editor using OpenCV3 and numpy.
I wanted to implement a Fourier Transform and used the first example from [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_transforms/py_fourier_transform/py_fourier_transform.html) with numpy:

```
f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))
```

I can't just use `fshift` as result and display it. Unfortunately the line with `20*np.log...` isn't explained on the site and reading other explanations for the fourier transform didn't explain it to me either.

Until now i have no parameter for this manipulation, but I tested that the output differs if I change 20 to something else. Should this be user configurable or why does this code example do this?

Comment: `20*log(abs(f))` is typically used to generate a dB magnitude scale, which is not particularly appropriate for images (it's normally used for audio), but it probably gives a reasonable range of values for plotting. It's just arbitrary scaling of a log axis for display purposes though, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850896/3005167), `fshift` is complex and cannot be displayed directly. If you want to see the spectrum you need to take the absolute value.

However, there is a reason for taking the logarithm. The values of the spectrum vary over a great range. So, often you only see a single peak (or in 2D a bright spot) at the center. The logarithm compresses the range of values - larger peaks are scaled down more than smaller peaks. This is useful for visualization because it allows you to see details at all amplitudes.

Here is an illustration:

[image]

Note that the scaling factor of 20 has a physical meaning for signals:

```
20 * log(abs(f)) = 10 * log(abs(f)^2)
```

The factor 10 is arbitrary, but the factor 2 (2*10) is equivalent to squaring the spectrum before taking fhe logarithm. If you only want to visualize the FFT, this factor does not matter - only the logarithm is important.

Comment: post title is a little weird and I think this great explanation should be in a post with better title.( it's a little bit hard to find it)

Comment: There is not much I can do because my answer is permanently attached to the question. However, you could edit the title to make it easier to find. Alternatively, you could post a better question and mark it as a duplicate so that it links here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display `fshift` because it is a complex array. You can only plot real valued arrays.

```
In [26]: fshift.dtype
Out[26]: dtype('complex128')
```

`np.abs` returns the modulus or magnitude of those complex numbers.

You can see the parameters of fft in the [numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html). Remark that Scipy also has a [fft implementation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html#module-scipy.fftpack), a wrapper of fftpack. Last, you may find the [scipy tutorial on Fourier Transforms](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html) useful.